# GREP - words won't match in Windows PowerShell

Tags: regex, bash, shell, powershell, grep

I been learning grep throughout these last couple of days. And I did all online.

Now I am trying to GREP through the command line in GITBASH Windows PowerShell.
But I won't get any matched results and some expressions seems to be invalid which worked online.

[image]

In this command I don't get any results back, but there are matching words inside.

[image]

In this I get an error that there is no such file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So how can i do that?

Comment: `grep` uses POSIX BRE as its default so you have to escape curly braces: `e[a-z]\{2\}y`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Recent Windows versions don't provide the grep alias. The error message in the 2nd image points to a native grep - so I think revo is right with the curly brace escaping.

Comment: @revo thank you. it works. But what should i do in this \b[^aeiou\s]{6,}\b . How can \b is not recognised

Comment: FYI: BRE doesn't support `\s` metacharacter but supports `\b`. If you don't see right output that's 'cause you didn't use `-o` option: `grep -o -e '\b[^aeiou]\{6,\}\b' file`

Answer (score 0):

grep uses POSIX BRE as its default so I had to escape curly braces:

```
e[a-z]\{2\}y
```